# Flexiprovider -- SecretKey manipulation

Tags: java, encryption, aes

I'm using flexiprovider do some test about encrypting and decrypting text files using AES. I want to encrypt a text file, then encrypt the original but changing 1 bit of the key and then analyze the disturbance or variation between the two encrypted files but I'm keep getting this error "Exception in thread "main" java.security.InvalidKeyException: Unsupported key."
Well, here's my code

```
public static void perturbacaoAES() throws Exception {
    Security.addProvider(new FlexiCoreProvider());

    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES128_CBC", "FlexiCore");
    KeyGenerator keyGen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES", "FlexiCore");
    SecretKey secKey = keyGen.generateKey();

    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secKey);

    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("Zero.txt");
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("ZeroCifrado.txt");
    try (CipherOutputStream cos = new CipherOutputStream(fos, cipher)) {
        byte[] block = new byte[8];
        int i;
        while ((i = fis.read(block)) != -1) {
            cos.write(block, 0, i);
        }
    }
    fis.close();
    fos.close();

    byte[] newKey = secKey.getEncoded();

    newKey[0] ^= 1 << 1;

    secKey = new SecretKeySpec(newKey, "AES128_CBC");

    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secKey);

    FileInputStream nfis = new FileInputStream("Zero.txt");
    FileOutputStream nfos = new FileOutputStream("ZeroChaveCifrado.txt");
    try (CipherOutputStream cos = new CipherOutputStream(nfos, cipher)) {
        byte[] block = new byte[8];
        int i;
        while ((i = nfis.read(block)) != -1) {
            cos.write(block, 0, i);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: If you get a, "Unsupported key" exception examine the key! `AES128_CBC` expects a 128-bit (16-byte) key.  Display both `secKey`,  `newKey` and `secKey` (yes, both values of `secKey`) **in hex notation** and add to the question. It also does not help debugging to reuse the variable `secKey`

Comment: The answer to your experiment is that approximately 50% of the bits will change. Otherwise there would be some information about the key that could be obtained from the output and that would be failing encryption and security .

Comment: The SecretKeySpec type should not specify mode, and I'm not sure for Flexi but on the standard providers it should not specify size. Try "AES" or at most "AES128".

Comment: Well, looks like the method was expecting a RijndaelKey object and not a SecretKeySpec object.

Answer (score 0):

Well, looks like the method was expecting a RijndaelKey object and not a SecretKeySpec object.